# Sigma algebra generated by sets in the range of a function

Tags: measure-theory

This is Bartle's The Elements of Integration, Exercise 2.O.

Let $(X,\bf{X})$ be a measurable space and $f$ defined on $X$ to $Y$.Let $\bf A$ be a collection of subsets of $Y$ such that $\forall E\in \bf{A}$$: f^{-1}(E)\in \bf X$. Show that $\forall F\in \sigma(\bf{A})$$: f^{-1}(F)\in \bf X$, where $\sigma(\bf{A})$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\bf A$.

I thought of this solution:

Let $\bf Y$ be a collection of subsets of $Y$ defined as:

$\bf Y$$=\left\{E\subset Y: f^{-1}(E)\in\bf{X}\right\}$$\implies \bf Y$ is a sigma algebra.

By definition we know $\bf A$ $\subset \bf Y$. Since $\sigma(\bf{A})$ is the smallest sigma algebra that contains the sets in $\bf A$, then it must be the case that $\sigma(\bf A)$ $\subset \bf Y$, which implies that $\forall F\in \sigma(\bf{A})$$: f^{-1}(F)\in \bf X$, since if $F\in \sigma(\bf{A})$$\implies F\in \bf Y$.

My question is if it is true that $\sigma(\bf A)$ $\subset \bf Y$ by definition of these two sigma algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $E$ in $ \bf A$, we have $f^{-1} (E) \in \bf X$, so $\bf A \subset Y$.

This implies that $\sigma(\bf A) \subset \sigma(\bf Y) = \bf Y$.